# Typescript preset keys with keyof

Tags: typescript

I want to have a preset of keys but I don't want to limit the user to use only these.

```
type B = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

type T = keyof B | string;


function someFunc(key: T) {}

someFunc(); // key type is `T`
```

In the above case, I want to get autocomplete for `a` and `b`, but users can also use any string they want. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler reduces the union `"a" | "b" | string` to just `string`.  This is "correct" from the perspective of the type system, since you want to accept any `string` value, and `"a"` and `"b"` are just specific ones.  But from the perspective of IntelliSense and completion lists for IDE hinting, the type `string` has lost information that `"a" | "b" | string` had.  Ideally you'd like the compiler to continue to collapse such unions to `string` while remembering to *suggest* `"a"` and `"b"` when you try to write a value of that type in your IDE.

Unfortunately this is currently not a feature of TypeScript.  There are actually multiple issues in GitHub filed about this, and you may want to go to one or all of them and give them a .  The big one is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729), and it looks like this issue will actually be reviewed by the design team soon (as of 2020-05-23).  There's also [microsoft/TypeScript#26277](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26277), [microsoft/TypeScript#33471](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33471), and [microsoft/TypeScript#34714](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34714). For the short term, though, this is not part of the language, and so if you want something like it you'll have to use a workaround.

The workarounds I've seen involve defining a type for which the compiler will accept any `string` value, but a reduction to `string` is avoided or deferred because it depends on some unspecified generic type.  For example:

```
function someFunc<S extends string>(key: S | keyof B) { }
```

Here, we've made `someFunc()` generic in `S` which is constrained to `string`.  The `key` parameter is of type `S | keyof B`.  Whatever string value you type in for `key` will end up being the inferred type for `S`, so it will accept any `string`:

```
someFunc("a"); // okay
someFunc("b"); // okay
someFunc("omega"); // okay
```

But the autocomplete will suggest `"a"` and `"b"` because it doesn't know what `S` is when it has to make the suggestions:

[image]

Hooray!  I'm sure there are plenty of edge cases involved in turning what was supposed to be a concrete type into a generic type, and you might conclude that the side-effects are not worth it for you.  It is a workaround after all, so tread lightly.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UDeBYAUFTUCGAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYDc6WUARvuQK4C2DExtaAvuugBmLcgGNgpAPblCkthABiI0QB4AylAgAPYBHIATAoRIVKAPgAUAawgh8GgD5QbISYNgBKZFH5p0BOUVlCwAibBCPaigAemioSStsEH9ApTFQhgio2PjE5LQA+TTRUMDKcMiYuISk9CA)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type B = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

type C = {[key:string]: string | number } & B

const c: C = {
  a: "123",
  b: 123,
  d: "123"
}
```

With working auto completion. Check out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=11&pln=9&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gNxpQBGOJArgLY0QFUC%20KKokUAwgmQBtANYQQWfMXIBdHNNJkoAHyiMWbKBygAyWNwDGAexL4ohnIMSp02KACIAjACYAzA4A01OlFdvvdAATHGd3BxQOIA)

Comment: You mean, you want your parameter to be of either type 'a', 'b' or string?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want.

Comment: The problem here is, that the keys are always of type string or int. And even if you specify it like this:
`type A = string; type B = number; type T = A | B | string`
it will just say that T is either a number or a string, because it uses translative interference.